# Контроль размера элемента VerticalLayoutGroup

Tags: unity3d, ui

Проблема: при включенном свойстве `Control Child Size` компонент `VerticalLayoutGroup` (и `HorizontalLayoutGroup`) тоже растягивает или сжимает `LayoutElement`'ы, чтобы они идеально входили.

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы элементы **сжимались**, когда не влезают, но ***НЕ*** растягивались, даже если есть место?

Например на первом изображении элемент не должен растягиваться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли это силами уже имеющихся компонентов?

Comment: По сути тебе нужны параметры `MaxWidth`/`MaxHeight`  для `LayoutElement`, но таких нет, только `Min`.

Comment: @Yaroslav Очень приятно слышать, что таких не существует! :) И что делать? Писать свои?

Comment: Я бы пересмотрел вёрстку ui. Размер одного и того-же элемента пляшет, вообще так особо не делают.